# Java based site map generator api

Tags: java, open-source, sitemap

I am looking out for a java based site map generator api which I can use to generate site map and target urls. It would be nice if the api is customizable by adding additional code into it.

The site map generator is for the sites that are already hosted. Thanks.

Regards,
J

Comment: What would it use for input?  Do you want it to spider the site?

Comment: @Ed: Yes that is right, something like an entry point URL and then generate site map from it

Comment: http://freeware.web-max.ca/ajSitemap.php

Answer (score 2):

I will say its rather trivial to write your own library as the XML schema is very simple. You can do this with JAXB fragment output.

Below is an some example on how you would write this XML. You'll have to make a Sitemap and Url JAXB POJO but this is rather easy. I probably post the entire code on gist later.

The important thing is that these methods take iterators not lists. Thus you could load from a database the `Url` objects in chunks instead of other libraries that will load all the objects in memory.

```
    protected final static String URLSET_START = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" + 
                    "<urlset xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n" + 
                    "         xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd\"\n" + 
                    "         xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n";
    protected final static String URLSET_END = "\n</urlset>";

    protected final static String SITEMAPINDEX_START = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" + 
    "<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n" + 
                    "         xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd\"\n" + 
                    "         xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n";
    protected final static String SITEMAPINDEX_END = "\n</sitemapindex>";

    public static void writeSitemapIndex(Writer writer, Iterator<? extends Sitemap> mappings) throws IOException {
            writeXml(writer, SITEMAPINDEX_START, mappings, SITEMAPINDEX_END);
    }

    public static long writeUrlset(Writer writer, Iterator<Url> urls) throws IOException {
            return writeXml(writer, URLSET_START, urls, URLSET_END);
    }

    private static long writeXml(Writer writer, String start, Iterator<?> it, String end) throws IOException {
            writer.write(start);
            long count = writeSubtree(writer, it);
            writer.write(end);
            return count;
    }

    public static long writeSubtree(Writer writer, Iterator<?> it) throws IOException {
            long size = 0;
            Marshaller m;
            try {
                    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Sitemap.class, Url.class);
                    m = jc.createMarshaller();
                    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
                    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            } catch (PropertyException e) {
                    throw new DataBindingException(e);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    throw new DataBindingException(e);
            }

            boolean first = true;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                    if (first) first = false;
                    else writer.write("\n");
                    try {
                            m.marshal(it.next(), writer);
                    } catch (JAXBException e) {
                            throw new IOException(e);
                    }
                    size++;
            }
            return size;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one -   sitemapgen4j:

http://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/

Comment: I have my own implementation that I'm considering open sourcing after looking at this project because this one is not stream/iterator based. The project you reference will store all 50k URLs in memory and loop through them to write each URL.

Comment: Go ahead! What will it be - a servlet? Or simply a stream? I currently use a Wicket page, which loads the data from DB (JPA), but in the end also constructs the whole page in memory. But I could use a stream to serve the request.

Comment: No I stream it from Solr. Much faster than from a database. Then if its big enough and I don't want it updated all the time I save it as a file and pass it to [**Tomcat's sendfile**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html#Asynchronous_writes)

Comment: @AdamGent is it possible for you to share your code implementations?